# Вид сказуемого

Tags: сказуемое

Уважаемые друзья, мы в последнее время много говорили о  сказуемых, и у меня возник вопрос по этой теме: как определить вид сказуемых в двух похожих  примерах:

> Ему пришлось нелегко.
>
> Ему пришлось уехать.

Спасибо за ваше внимание.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Ему пришлось нелегко** - составное именное сказуемое. **Пришлось** - знаменательная связка, **нелегко** - категория состояния, не глагол, значит, именное.

**Ему пришлось уехать** - составное глагольное сказ., **пришлось** - вспомогательный глагол со значением необходимости (= "надо" ) + инфинитив.

Comment: Суть вопроса в следующем: 1) почему один и тот же глагола в разных видах сказуемого выполняет роль связки? 2) для глагольного сказуемого модальность глагола понятна, но в именном сказуемом знаменательный глагол-связка должен иметь значение движения/положения. Может быть, это неразложимое сочетание и простое сказуемое?

Comment: Используются разные значения слова. Пришлось нелегко - "прийтись" - (безл.) выпасть на долю https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D Пришлось уехать -"прийтись" - оказаться нужным, необходимым. Синонимы довелось, случилось= оказалось нужным уехать. А кто сказал, что "в именном сказуемом знаменательный глагол-связка должен иметь значение движения/положения"? глагол -связка может иметь значение проявления,обнаружения признака(оказался и др.),признака в чьём-либо исполнении(стать, остаться, сделаться),названия признака(зваться, почитаться)и движения/состояния.Пришлось=выпало на долю-проявление признака

Comment: Пришлось нелегко, стало нелегко, было нелегко, будет нелегко-вполне свободные сочетания, в смысле не фразеологизмы, другое дело, что разбирается как один член предл., т. е. слитное словосочетание, но ведь потому оно и СОСТАВНОЕ.А простое: долго мозолил глаза=надоедал. Фразеологизм должен замениться глаголом."Пришлось нелегко" нельзя заменить ГЛАГОЛОМ, только кат. состояния=было нелегко, следовательно, всё же именное.

Comment: Наверное, это полузнаменательная связка в именном сказуемом со значением, близким к связке "оказаться", да и глагол безличный, таких среди простых глагольных сказуемых нет. С другой стороны, в словаре глагол "пришлось" практически сочетается только с наречиями одной темы: пришлось плохо/трудно/нелегко/тяжело, поэтому похоже на устойчивое сочетание.

Comment: Это говорит о наличии синонимов, об ограниченной сочетаемости,а не об устойчивости,  сочетается преимущественно с категорией состояния.